# How do I set up a persistent process on a web server and connect to it from multiple sessions?

Tags: python, cgi

This may seem very basic but I have never done this before and am frankly kind of lost. Here is what I want to do:

- I want a process to run (a Python CGI script would be great) on a web server without ever stopping unless I tell it to die.
- I want any session to be able to communicate with that same process (i.e. not start a new CGI process for each session).

What is the best way to do this? I have been looking at FastCGI and my hosting service seems to support it, but I can't for the life of me find a usable example in any search because all results either seem to talk about running python or php itself as a FastCGI and not about my above-described problem.

Thanks